# Credit Memo - 'Email Copy of Credit Memo' how to set default ON

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

How to set the 'Email Copy of Credit Memo' checkbox to a default value of checked?

(So to negate the requirement to check the box every time)

Is there anyway to override the single input line within items.phtml, and not override the whole items.phtml template file?

Eg:

[image: Creditmemo email checkbox]

Comment: I can see that the checkbox is defined in    
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml  
  
  
  by manually adding the **checked** html attribute to the input it has the desired effect.
Any way to easily override this from custom theme code?    
    

     
 `<label class="normal" for="send_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email Copy of Credit Memo') ?></label>
              <input id="send_email" name="creditmemo[send_email]" value="1" type="checkbox" checked/>`

Comment: Very useful:  
[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30590/how-do-i-rewrite-a-single-element-in-a-phtml-file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30590/how-do-i-rewrite-a-single-element-in-a-phtml-file)