# How to not show GA on "Do Not Track" header

Tags: layout, ce-1.8.1.0, google-analytics

I would like to receive instructions on how to not echo Google Analytics JS when user browser send header "DNT".

I would like to know if:

1. Would i have to make an extension on the GA block class to get the $_SERVER to check whether it should return null or the JS code
2. Would there be any way to do that on XML
3. Should i do it on the "display" (i mean the design/template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Would i have to make an extension on the GA block class to get the $_SERVER to check whether it should return null or the JS code

Yes I think you need to add your own code. [A way to detect the DNT header can be found from Robert Lerner](http://www.robert-lerner.com/do-not-track-headers-in-php.php)

> 2) Would there be any way to do that on XML

I think no. [What you could do is implement a helper and depending on the return value of the helper do something](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3207/217). So you could add a DNT-value to the block, you can check in the template and then do nothing

> 3) Should i do it on the "display" (i mean the design/template)

No, I would implement everything in your own block, check the DNT there and then just call the method in your template to do something - or not.

I think this is business logic and therefore it belongs in a model, controller, helper or block, but definitely not in a template.

I prefer the block over the helper.