# Changing Product reviews tab contents

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, review

I want to change the product reviews tab contents.
I could do that with XML files:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>product.reviews</name>
    </action>
    <block type="reviewcontainer/tabs" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" after="additional">
        <action method="addToParentGroup">
            <group>detailed_info</group>
        </action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
            <value>My Reviews</value>
        </action>
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/review_tab.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

However I have some settings in the System/Configuration page that should control if the reviews are changed. So my question is how can I do this from code?

Comment: check if condition in layout file [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/if-condition-in-layout-xml-tag)

Comment: Hi,

thanks for Your answer, however I need some more help :-\

So I need to have a widget, that replaces the reviews tab and it decides if the original tab data and title renders or my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` tag can have an attribute `ifconfig` like this:

```
<action ifconfig="your/config/path" method="unsetChild">
```

Adding blocks with `<block>` conditionally is not possible out-of-the box but here's a workaround:

Create the block outside of the layout hierarchy (only specify the block name here):

```
<catalog_product_view>

    ...

    <block type="reviewcontainer/tabs" name="product.reviews" />

</catalog_product_view>
```

and then add it conditionally using the `insert` action (specify position and alias here):

```
<catalog_product_view>

    ...

    <reference name="product.info">
        <action ifconfig="your/config/path" method="insert">
            <name>product.reviews</name>
            <sibling>additional</sibling>
            <after>true</after>
            <as>reviews</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.reviews">
        <action ifconfig="your/config/path" method="addToParentGroup">
            <group>detailed_info</group>
        </action>
        <action ifconfig="your/config/path" method="setTitle" translate="value">
            <value>My Reviews</value>
        </action>
        <action ifconfig="your/config/path" method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/review_tab.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

I also moved all actions on the reviews block to a reference, and made them conditional with `ifconfig`. You don't need to do that but it's making the separation of block definition and block usage more clear IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I read about the ifconfig, but all the first search results were mentioned with some modules and because of those I thought that it is provided by a module.